# Unir datos entre columnas de 2 csv segun si los datos de una columna coinciden con otra

Tags: python, pandas, csv

alguien sabría una manera muy concreta para combinar las columnas de dos CSV?

Me gustaria crear un csv a partir de otros haciendo que en la columna 'Evento' y 'Respuesta se añadan los eventos del segundo csv pero justo en la misma fila en la que coincidan por tiempo con el primer csv.

```
csv1 = [
[1, Tiempo, Evento, Respuesta],
[2,  00.01,       ,          ],
[3,  00.12,       ,          ],
[4,  00.58,       ,          ],
[5,  00.73,       ,          ]
]

csv2 = [
[1, Tiempo, Evento, Respuesta],
[2,  00.12,  'x'  ,          ],
[3,  00.73,  'y'  ,    'y'   ]
]

resultado_esperado = [
[1, Tiempo, Evento, Respuesta],
[2,  00.01,       ,          ],
[3,  00.12,  'x'  ,          ],
[4,  00.58,       ,          ],
[5,  00.73,  'y'  ,    'y'   ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable **no** utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces `apply` podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

Puedes realizarlo fácilmente al utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), únicamente tenemos que utilizar las columnas "Tiempo" de ambos `dataframes` como índices, realizar el `update` y luego utilizar `reset_index()` para recuperar el índice original del primer `dataframe`.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Tiempo': [00.01, 00.12, 00.58, 00.73],
                    'Evento': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                    'Respuesta': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Tiempo': [00.12, 00.73],
                    'Evento': ['x', 'y'],
                    'Respuesta': [np.nan, 'y']})

# Convertimos la columna Tiempo a índice
df1.set_index('Tiempo', inplace = True)
df1.update(df2.set_index('Tiempo'))
df1.reset_index(inplace = True)
print(df1)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
   Tiempo Evento Respuesta
0    0.01    NaN       NaN
1    0.12      x       NaN
2    0.58    NaN       NaN
3    0.73      y         y
```

Y al final puedes utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) para crear el `csv` resultante.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Este código funciona perfecto. Pero si complicamos un poco mas el ejemplo suponiendo que: `df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Tiempo','Evento'])`  en este caso con tu ejemplo `df1.set_index('Tiempo', inplace = True)
df1.update(df2.set_index('Tiempo'))
df1.reset_index(inplace = True)
print(df1)` nos daría un dataframe vacío. ¿Como se podría solucionar?

Comment: No entiendo que quisieras hacer con eso, con lo que pusiste estás creando un `dataframe` vacío al inicio, luego haces un par de operaciones y luego imprimes `df1` que sigue vacío y claramente no puede hacer `update` porque las entradas no existen.

Comment: En este nuevo caso la intención seria que al dataframe vacio se le añadan los datos de un dataframe con datos. Como por ejemplo el df2 o un supuesto df3 con nuevos datos y que se añadan al df1 vacio del mismo modo que sucede en tu ejemplo

Comment: Ya veo, yo creo que lo mejor es que lo intentes resolver y si hay algún error crear una nueva pregunta ya que es importante mantener una sola pregunta por publicación para que las respuestas sean útiles. Una pista, `update` no serviría para ese caso. Saludos!

Comment: Genial! Así lo he hecho. Comparto el enlace del nuevo hilo por si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema que yo: *https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/579255/unir-datos-entre-csv-totalmente-distintos-combinando-los-datos-de-una-columna*

Answer (score -1):

Al principio probé creando un csv vacío para los resultados, y luego a través de pandas abrir los 3 csv:

```
import pandas as pd

#Creo el csv vacio donde almacenar los resultados y los cargo con pandas
resultado_esperado = "/filepath/resultado.csv"
with open(resultado_esperado, 'w') as f:
        f.write("Tiempo; Evento; Respuesta")
    f.close()

df_resultado = pd.read_csv(csv, sep =';')
df_csv1 = pd.read_csv(csv1, sep =';')
df_csv_2 = pd.read_csv(csv2, sep =';')

#Añado al csv con los resultados los tiempos del primer csv y guardo el archivo
df_resultado['Tiempo'] = df_csv1['Tiempo']
df.to_csv(csv, sep =';')


#Aqui es donde tengo el fallo:
for i in range (len(df['Tiempo']):
       if df_resultado['Tiempo'][i] == df_csv1['Tiempo'][i]:
           df_resultado['Evento'][i] = df_csv2['Evento'][i]
```

En los pasos previos todo esta correcto pero en el ultimo paso, hago un bucle condicional en el que pretendo que por cada fila si coincide el 'Tiempo' me añada en esa misma fila el 'Evento' correspondiente del csv2.

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o debería ser una edición a la pregunta?