# Unir datos entre csv totalmente distintos combinando los datos de una columna

Tags: python, pandas

Me gustaría crear un csv a partir de otros haciendo que en la columna 'TIMESTAMP' coincidan los valores. Es decir son varios csv con registros en un determinado momento (Timestamp), pero cada csv tiene unas características distintas (diferentes columnas y distintos index). Por ejemplo:

csv1=

```
          TIMESTAMP  DIAMETRO_A   VALIDEZ_A  DIAMETRO_B   VALIDEZ_B
0     648991.609642         NaN         0.0         NaN         0.0
1     648991.626300         NaN         0.0         NaN         0.0
2     648991.642958         NaN         0.0         NaN         0.0
...             ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
4053  649059.124545         NaN         0.0         NaN         0.0
4054  649059.141203         NaN         0.0         NaN         0.0

[4055 rows x 5 columns]
```

csv2=

```
          TIMESTAMP      POS_X      POS_Y        POS_Z        POS_W  DISTANCIA
0     648998.969022  -0.298566  -0.231037     0.187898     0.062068   0.567942
1     648999.569554  -0.298566  -0.231037     0.187898     0.062068   0.567942
2     648999.598977  -0.298566  -0.231037     0.187898     0.062068   0.567942
...             ...        ...        ...          ...          ...        ...
1525  649051.301615   0.033240   0.124051    -0.037196    -0.128318   0.262014
1526  649051.334954   0.032453   0.122992    -0.037020    -0.127867   0.260301

[1527 rows x 6 columns]
```

csv3=

```
       TIMESTAMP      CODIGO
0  648998.962540         100
1  649007.309212         111
2  649022.804688         111

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Querría unirlos en uno solo de manera que compartan la columna TIMESTAMP, pero siguiendo el orden de los tiempos de esa columna de este modo:

Resultado_Esperado=

```
                   TIMESTAMP  EVENT_CODE  R_DIAMETER  R_VALIDITY  L_DIAMETER  L_VALIDITY  RED_POS_X  RED_POS_Y  GREEN_POS_X GREEN_POS_Y  BALL_DIST
0     6.489.916.096.423.030         NaN         NaN         0.0         NaN         0.0  -0.298566  -0.231037     0.187898  0.06206836   0.567942
1     6.489.916.263.003.100       100.0         NaN         0.0         NaN         0.0  -0.298566  -0.231037     0.187898  0.06206836   0.567942
2     6.489.916.429.583.170         NaN         NaN         0.0         NaN         0.0  -0.298566  -0.231037     0.187898  0.06206836   0.567942
3     6.489.916.596.163.240       111.0         NaN         0.0         NaN         0.0  -0.298566  -0.231037     0.187898  0.06206836   0.567942
4     6.489.916.762.743.310       111.0         NaN         0.0         NaN         0.0  -0.298566  -0.231037     0.187898  0.06206836   0.567942
...                     ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...        ...        ...          ...         ...        ...
```

Los timestamps que no aparezcan en una columna de un csv se tendrian que añadir desde los otros para evitar perder informacion. Es decir si un csv tiene timestamps 1,3,5  y el otro tiene 1,2,3  y otro solo con 1, 4 en el resultado esten todos: 1,2,3,4,5.

Al principio pensé que era mas simple y probé con el código hablado en un hilo anterior relacionado:
*[Unir datos entre columnas de 2 csv segun si los datos de una columna coinciden con otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/579083/unir-datos-entre-columnas-de-2-csv-segun-si-los-datos-de-una-columna-coinciden-c/579084?noredirect=1#comment1023738_579084)*

Pero esto es bastante mas complejo y no consigo dar con la forma de hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con el método "merge" de pandas, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Leerás los tres archivos, los cuales yo elegí nombres arbitrarios, cámbialos según tus necesidades:

```
import pandas as pd
csv1 = pd.read_csv("data1.csv")
csv2 = pd.read_csv("data2.csv")
csv3 = pd.read_csv("data3.csv")
```

Luego haz un merge de los tres DataFrames y obtendrás uno nuevo, el cual rellenará los valores faltantes con NaN.

```
ndata = csv1.merge(csv2, how="outer").merge(csv3, how="outer")
```

Teniendo en cuenta que no tomé todas las columnas que tú tienes, por cuestiones de tiempo y asigné valores aleatorios, esto dará como salida por ejemplo:

```
        TIMESTAMP  DIAMETRO  VALIDEZ   POS  DISTANCIA  CODIGO
0       68990       2.0      0.0   NaN        NaN   117.0
1       68991       3.0      1.0   NaN        NaN    95.0
2       68992       2.0      1.0   NaN        NaN   106.0
3       68993      23.0      1.0   NaN        NaN     NaN
4       68994       3.0      0.0   4.0        9.0     NaN
5       68995       2.0      0.0   9.0        3.0     NaN
6       68996       2.0      1.0  15.0       18.0     NaN
7       68997       NaN      NaN  20.0       19.0     NaN
8       68998       NaN      NaN  21.0        5.0     NaN
9       68999       NaN      NaN  12.0       21.0     NaN
10      69000       NaN      NaN   5.0       15.0     NaN
11      68986       NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN    99.0
12      68987       NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN   107.0
13      68988       NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN   113.0
14      68989       NaN      NaN   NaN        NaN   110.0
```

Espero haber entendido tu problema y haberte ayudado, si es así me harías un gran favor marcando como correcta la respuesta.

Comment: La solución final es junto con lo que tu has hecho, convertir los valores de la columna 'TIMESTAMP' en float (o int, según la necesidad de cada uno) con `df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['TIMESTAMP'].astype(float)` y despues ordenar las filas según ese valor mediante `df.sort_values(by=['TIMESTAMP'], inplace=True, ascending=False)`